# Use regular reference instead of `Box` in recursive data structures

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust. When I read chapter 15 of *The Rust Programming Language*, I failed to know why one should use `Box`es in recursive data structures instead of regular references. 15.1 of the book explains that indirection is required to avoid infinite-sized structures, but it does not explain why to use `Box`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum FunctionalList<'a> {
    Cons(u32, &'a FunctionalList<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use FunctionalList::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let list = Cons(1, &Cons(2, &Cons(3, &Nil)));

    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

The code above compiles and produces the desired output. It seems that using `FunctionalList` to store a small amount of data on stack works perfectly well. Does this code cause troubles?

Comment: How is it that this is possible given the issue with the recursive types being unsized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that the `FunctionalList` works in this simple case. However, we will run into some difficulties if we try to use this structure in other ways. For instance, suppose we tried to construct a `FunctionalList` and then return it from a function:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum FunctionalList<'a> {
    Cons(u32, &'a FunctionalList<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use FunctionalList::{Cons, Nil};

fn make_list(x: u32) -> FunctionalList {
    return Cons(x, &Cons(x + 1, &Cons(x + 2, &Nil)));
}

fn main() {
    let list = make_list(1);

    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

This results in the following compile error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:9:25
  |
9 | fn make_list(x: u32) -> FunctionalList {
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime: `FunctionalList + 'static`
```

If we follow the hint and add a `'static` lifetime, then we instead get this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |     return Cons(x, &Cons(x + 1, &Cons(x + 2, &Nil)));
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------^^
   |            |                     |
   |            |                     temporary value created here
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The issue is that the inner `FunctionalList` values here are owned by implicit temporary variables whose scope ends at the end of the `make_list` function. These values would thus be dropped at the end of the function, leaving dangling references to them, which Rust disallows, hence the borrow checker rejects this code.

In contrast, if `FunctionalList` had been defined to `Box` its `FunctionalList` component, then ownership would have been moved from the temporary value into the containing `FunctionalList`, and we would have been able to return it without any problem.

With your original `FunctionalList`, the thing we have to think about is that every value in Rust has to have an owner somewhere; and so if, as in this case, the `FunctionaList` is not the owner of its inner `FunctionalList`s, then that ownership has to reside somewhere else. In your example, that owner was an implicit temporary variable, but in more complex situations we could use a different kind of external owner. Here's an example of using a `TypedArena` (from the [typed-arena](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/2.0.1/typed_arena/) crate) to own the data, so that we can still implement a variation of the `make_list` function:

```
use typed_arena::Arena;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum FunctionalList<'a> {
    Cons(u32, &'a FunctionalList<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use FunctionalList::{Cons, Nil};

fn make_list<'a>(x: u32, arena: &'a Arena<FunctionalList<'a>>) -> &mut FunctionalList<'a> {
    let l0 = arena.alloc(Nil);
    let l1 = arena.alloc(Cons(x + 2, l0));
    let l2 = arena.alloc(Cons(x + 1, l1));
    let l3 = arena.alloc(Cons(x, l2));
    return l3;
}

fn main() {
    let arena = Arena::new();
    let list = make_list(1, &arena);

    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

In this case, we adapted the return type of `make_list` to return only a mutable reference to a `FunctionalList`, instead of returning an owned `FunctionalList`, since now the ownership resides in the `arena`.