# How to specify a lifetime for a borrow in a struct in Rust?

Tags: recursion, rust, struct, nodes, trie

I have a Trie struct whose nodes have children which are also nodes:

```rust
pub struct Trie<'a, T: marker::Copy> {
  nodes: [Option<TrieNode<'a, T>>; MAX_NODE_LEN],
  min_len: usize,
  max_len: usize
}

pub struct TrieNode<'a, T> {
  children: [Option<&'a TrieNode<'a, T>>; CHILDREN_COUNT],
  value: Option<T>
}
```

I am using `Option` for both fixed-size arrays as then I can simply initialize them as `[None; CHILDREN_COUNT]`, for example.

As I am using a borrowed value for the children of the node (as using a direct value causes an infinite declaration and thus would require infinite memory), I am getting an issue later on when I try to set one of the children:

```rust
pub fn add_node(&mut self, [...]) {
  // [...]
  if self.children[idx].is_none() {
    self.children[idx] = Some(&TrieNode::new());
  }
  // [...]
}
```

I know why this is failing: the borrowed `TrieNode::new()` is being dropped at the end of the function, however I don't know how to go about this best.

I tried specifying the lifetime:

```rust
Some(&'a TrieNode::new());
```

but was told I cannot annotate borrow expressions with lifetimes, leading me to asking this, namely how should I go about storing an array of references to the same struct, which I can allocate in a function within an impl of said struct?

Comment: Don't use references, use `Box`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use regular reference instead of \`Box\` in recursive data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368330/use-regular-reference-instead-of-box-in-recursive-data-structures)

Comment: As an alternative to using `[Option<Box<U>>; N]` as others suggest, you can just use `Vec<U>` (or `Vec<Option<U>>` if you absolutely need holes). The real issue is that you're trying to make a reference to a local variable outlive its scope.